# How to show memory usage in cocos2D 2

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I think it would be very handy to see how much memory is used and is still available in a cocos2d app.

I found this link: (http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2010/07/coding-cocos/) that describes how to do this for cocos2d v1 but in cocos2d 2 this "showFPS function" is done in a completely different way.

So can anybody explain to me how to show memory usage next to the FPS in cocos2d 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the whole application memory usage via code. At least for iOS devices. cocos2d only allows you to see how much memory is consumed with loaded textures. If you want to see how much memory your application consumes, use Instruments tool. It is the part of XCode bundle.

If you just want to see how much memory is consumed by loaded textures, just call

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];
```

You'll see this info in the console.